# how to pass url link in dockerfile to create different containers based on url argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile, command-line-arguments

i have dockerfile which is;

```
FROM centos/systemd
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
RUN yum install  xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-apps bzip2 wget gtk3 initscripts sudo -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y install xrdp tigervnc-server
RUN cd /usr/local
RUN wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/76.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-76.0.tar.bz2
RUN tar xvjf firefox-76.0.tar.bz2
RUN ln -s /firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
RUN systemctl enable xrdp
RUN echo "/usr/bin/firefox --private-window --kiosk https://facebook.com" >~/.xsession
RUN chmod +x ~/.xsession
```

it creates image and then, containers generated from this image. but i want some containers open different url than

```
kiosk https://facebook.com
```

ie: twitter.com, instagram.com etc.
by using same image.
how can i pass this url argument?
is there a way that i can run it with my docker run command?

**edit**
my file.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
url=$1
echo "/usr/bin/firefox --private-window --kiosk $url " >/root/.xsession
chmod +x /root/.xsession
tail -f /dev/null
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/systemd
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
RUN yum install  xorg-x11-server-Xorg xorg-x11-xauth xorg-x11-apps bzip2 wget gtk3 initscripts sudo -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum -y install xrdp tigervnc-server
RUN cd /usr/local
RUN wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/76.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-76.0.tar.bz2
RUN tar xvjf firefox-76.0.tar.bz2
RUN ln -s /firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox
RUN systemctl enable xrdp
RUN touch ~/.xsession
COPY ./file.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/init","-D","FOREGROUND","./file.sh"]
RUN echo 'root:basak' | chpasswd
```

but it still does not write url. where is the problem?